# How turn off TableSorter bottom header

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

As soon as I add the `scroller` widget the bottom header appear. And I cant find a way to remove it.

```
$table.tablesorter({
            theme: 'blue',
            widthFixed: true,
            widgets: ["zebra", "scroller"],
            widgetOptions: {
                scroller_height: 100,
                scroller_upAfterSort: false,
                scroller_jumpToHeader: false
            }
        });
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have a `<tfoot>` in your table?

Comment: OK, I see it now. I just copy paste the sample.